# PostgreSQL log duration only on slow queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Is there a way in PostgreSQL 11.2 to log the duration only for the slow queries?

If I set

```
log_duration=off
log_min_duration_statement=2000
```

The slow statements are logged, but I have no idea how long they took. If I set:

```
log_duration=on
log_min_duration_statement=2000
```

then the duration of each statement is printed in the log.

There are no tags in the `log_line_prefix` parameter to include query duration.

Comment: The situation you describe is exactly as documented: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DURATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the parameter log_statement was wrongly set to 'all', after setting:

```
log_statement = 'none'
log_duration=off
log_min_duration_statement=2000
```

The log correctly traces only long queries and also writes their duration (after the prefix)